# Grab links from a chat box and save them to CSV formatted file

Tags: html, csv, hyperlink, web-scraping, xidel

I'm using "Link Klipper" chrome extension, with regular expressions to grab links from my html live cbox chat, this extension can save CSV file, but sometimes, it didn't work as expected.

```
<div class="Center" style="text-align: left">
 <br>
   <a class="MyURL" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/mylink" target="_blank">
    <font size=3 color="#333333" style="text-shadow: 0 0 0.1em black, 0 0 0.1em black,  0 0 0.1em black,  0 0 0.1em black,  0 0 0.1em black, 0 0 0.1em black, 0 0 0.1em black;">
      <b> My Link Name </b> 
    </font>
    <font size=3 color="#333333" style="text-shadow: 0 0 0.1em balck, 0 0 0.1em balck,  0 0 0.1em balck,  0 0 0.1em balck,  0 0 0.1em balck, 0 0 0.1em balck, 0 0 0.1em balck;">
      <b> Link Description </b>
    </font>
    <font size=3 color="#333333" style="text-shadow: 0 0 0.1em black, 0 0 0.1em black,  0 0 0.1em black,  0 0 0.1em black,  0 0 0.1em black, 0 0 0.1em black, 0 0 0.1em black;">
      <b> 100.0 MB </b>
    </font>
   </a>
 <br>
 </div>
```

Is there another effective method, maybe with **wget** or **xidel** to grab the link + name + description + size in a correctly formated CSV? or any supported human readable format.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
xidel -q example1.xml -e "//b"
```

or as a CSV:

```
xidel -q example1.xml -e "join(//b,',')"
```

Comment: I tried : `xidel "http://www.mywebsite.com" -e //DIV/B/A > C:\Users\User\Desktop\Links.txt` but I only get the Link Name, the URL is absent

Answer (score 0):

I grabed my links using xidel, and output the links to an html file using:

```
xidel "http://www.mywebsite.com" --html -e //BODY/DIV/B/A > c:\Users\User\Desktop\1.html
```